# User Inputs Value Into A Range - Rest Of Cells In Range Change Such That Sum of Range Still Equals A PreSet Num (Sudoku Lite)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to have a formula somewhat like a sum function. The only difference is that once it sums up the amounts of 3 cells (or more) it will edit a certain cell to maintain that total value if another cell is edited.

**For example:**

Column A, B, and C are each 3 and together equal 9:

```
| A  |  B  |  C |...| Total |
+----+-----+----+...+-------+
| 3  |  3  |  3 |...|   9   |
```

Columns A and B are edited to equal 2 each, but I still want to maintain the total of 9, so I want column C to automatically change to 5.

this:

```
| A  |  B  |  C |...| Total |
+----+-----+----+...+-------+
| 2  |  2  |  3 |...|   7   |
```

should update to:

```
| A  |  B  |  C |...| Total |
+----+-----+----+...+-------+
| 2  |  2  |  5 |...|   9   |
```

The reasoning behind this is because it is being sent to multiple parts of the country where only 2 cells will be edited, but I want to maintain a total without having to edit 2k+ rows of data inputs.

I'm open to a VBA option as well. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Any of the three cells can be edited?  This is not possible with formulas as you can have a formula or you can have a values but not both.  And formulas are live when the data changes so does the result.  VBA in a worksheet change event is the only way.

Comment: If the total is fixed for all rows, then that can be done. If not, it can still be done provided you have a list of all totals per row and then reference your formula there. So your formula will be in `C` where `A` and `B` are varying.

Comment: But D would be totaling A, B, and C. If a formula would be input in C referencing the changes in A and B, it would have a circular reference with D.

Comment: If that's the issue, you could simply use: `=9-SUM($A1:$B1)` in **C1** and `=SUBTOTAL(109,$A1:$C1)` in **D1** - @WilliamKaramanlis

Answer (score 1):

You can find the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716129/excel-formula-vba-to-keep-a-value-and-edit-cells-to-maintain-that-value/51717706#51717706).

The example:

Column A, B, and C are each 3 and together equal 9:

```
| A  |  B  |  C |...| Total |
+----+-----+----+...+-------+
| 3  |  3  |  3 |...|   9   |
```

Columns A and B are edited to equal 2 each, but I still want to maintain the total of 9, so I want column C to automatically change to 5:

```
| A  |  B  |  C |...| Total |
+----+-----+----+...+-------+
| 2  |  2  |  3 |...|   7   |
```

[image]

I realized that my code was a bit of a mess, so I broke it into sheet1, module main and a class named `CollectionOfGeneratedValues`.

> The only variables you have to adjust in your code are the `masterRange`, Columns in `rangeToFill` and  a column in `sumTarget` to suit your data input.

Quick runthrough:

- You have to set the `masterRange`, or the range that you are working with, inside VBA. Inside the spreadsheet you must set the `sumtarget` for each row of the `masterRange`.
- When a value is entered into a cell inside of your `masterRange`, we find out what row this is and generate a separate range that is just that row.
- If the input amount is greater than the `sumTarget` we `Exit Sub` and scold user.
- We generate an array of values whose sum, along with user input will be the `sumtarget`. We then take the sum target and subtract the user input.

  - Afterwards  generate a random number between 0 and the new `sumtarget.value`
  - We then store that rand number and subtract its value from `sumtarget`.
  - We do this `columnsInRange` - 1 times.
  - When we step out of the `for loop` for the last value we set the value to whatever is leftover of `sumtarget`.
  - With the collection that was created by the steps above we perform a `Fisher-Yates Shuffle`, so that we don't always the values of collection / our spreadsheet come in a descending order

UPDATE: Thank you for your comments, advice and help. I should have given more thought what form looks like. I have been left with some sort of weird dynamic / static hybrid. A custom UserForm that generates sets of these and then can print into a worksheet would have been cool. Regardless, I took most of Raystafarian's advice. Some of it, like where to store input checking logic, I prefer my way. But generally his advice is spot on. Thank you again.

**Sheet 1:**

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    SolveSudokuLite.Main target
End Sub
```

**Module `SolveSudokuLite`:**

Option Explicit
    Sub Main(ByRef target As Range)
    Dim masterRange                     As Range
    Dim rangeToFill                     As Range
    Dim valuesToFillRange               As GeneratedValuesCollection

```
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Set masterRange = Range("B1:E5")
        Set valuesToFillRange = New GeneratedValuesCollection
        If Not Intersect(masterRange, target) Is Nothing Then
            TargetSum.setTargetSum target
            If Not IsValidInput(target) Then Exit Sub
            valuesToFillRange.GenerateValues target
            PrintValues valuesToFillRange, target
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Function IsValidInput(ByVal target As Range) As Boolean
    IsValidInput = True
    If (target.value >= TargetSum.sum) Or Not IsNumeric(target.value) Then
        MsgBox ("WILL NOT CALCULATE FOR ROW " & target.Row & ", USER INPUT INVALID")
        IsValidInput = False
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Function

Function PrintValues(ByRef valuesToFillRange As GeneratedValuesCollection, ByVal target As Range)
Dim rangeToFill                     As Range
Dim collectionCounter               As Long
Dim cellInRangeToFill               As Range

    Set rangeToFill = Range("A" & target.Row & ":E" & target.Row)
    collectionCounter = 1
    For Each cellInRangeToFill In rangeToFill
        If cellInRangeToFill.Address = target.Address Then
            cellInRangeToFill.value = target.value
        Else
            cellInRangeToFill.value = valuesToFillRange.Item(collectionCounter)
            collectionCounter = collectionCounter + 1
        End If
    Next cellInRangeToFill
End Function
```

**Class named `GeneratedValuesCollection`:**

```
Option Explicit
Private GeneratedValuesCollection As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set GeneratedValuesCollection = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set GeneratedValuesCollection = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = GeneratedValuesCollection.Count
End Property

Public Sub Add(num As Long)
    GeneratedValuesCollection.Add num
End Sub

Public Property Get Item(Index As Variant) As Long
     Item = GeneratedValuesCollection.Item(Index)
End Property

Public Sub Clear()
    Set GeneratedValuesCollection = New Collection
End Sub

Public Sub GenerateValues(ByVal target As Range)
Dim userSetValue                    As Long
Dim sumLeft                         As Long
Dim numbersToGenerate               As Long

    userSetValue = target.value
    sumLeft = SetInitialSumLeft(userSetValue)
    numbersToGenerate = NumberValuesToGenerate(target)
    SetValues numbersToGenerate, sumLeft
End Sub

Private Function SetInitialSumLeft(ByVal userSetValue As Long) As Long
    SetInitialSumLeft = TargetSum.sum - userSetValue
End Function

Private Function NumberValuesToGenerate(ByVal target As Range) As Long
Dim rangeToFill                     As Range

    Set rangeToFill = Range("A" & target.Row & ":E" & target.Row)
    NumberValuesToGenerate = rangeToFill.Columns.Count - 1
End Function

Private Sub SetValues(ByVal numbersToGenerate As Long, ByVal sumLeft As Long)
Dim counter                         As Long
Dim value                           As Long

    For counter = 1 To numbersToGenerate - 1
        value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, sumLeft / 1.25)
        Me.Add value
        sumLeft = sumLeft - value
    Next counter
    Me.Add sumLeft
End Sub

Public Sub ShuffleCollection()
Dim holdValuesArray                As Collection

    Set holdValuesArray = DuplicateCollection()
    Swap holdValuesArray
End Sub

Private Function DuplicateCollection() As Collection
Dim counter                         As Long
Dim maxNum                          As Long

    Set DuplicateCollection = New Collection
    maxNum = Me.Count
    For counter = 1 To maxNum
        DuplicateCollection.Add Me.Item(counter)
    Next counter
End Function

Private Sub Swap(ByRef holdValuesArray As Collection)
Dim randomNum                       As Long
Dim maxNum                          As Long
Dim counter                         As Long

    Me.Clear
    maxNum = holdValuesArray.Count
    For counter = 1 To maxNum
        randomNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, holdValuesArray.Count)
        Me.Add (holdValuesArray(randomNum))
        holdValuesArray.Remove (randomNum)
    Next counter
End Sub
```

**Class named `TargetSum`:**

```
Option Explicit
Private CollectionOfGeneratedValues As Collection

Private Type TTargetSum
        sum As Long
End Type

Private this As TTargetSum

Public Property Get sum() As Long
    sum = this.sum
End Property

Public Sub setTargetSum(ByVal value As Range)
    this.sum = Range("F" & value.Row)
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you explain this through?

Comment: explained a bit, hope it helps