# Looking for a formule

Tags: excel, adwords-budgetservice

I'm a novice to Excel. I don't which formula to use. I want to set up a budget for 12 months, that quite easy ex. 12000/12= 1000 in 12 columns. I need a formula for when one column answer is changed by hand lets say to 2000, that will the remaining columns answers automatically change to 909.09. I don't which formula to use and if its do able?

Thanks for your help

Kind regards

Johan

Comment: It's not that simple. You've handled the case where you have 12 months @1000 per month = 12000 and one changes. What happens when two change (like month 1 & 3)? What happens when three are changed (like 2, 4, and 6)?

Comment: If it is acceptable to use VBA Macro then I will suggest VBA route to achieve this.

Comment: Also if you type manually it will overlay your formula for that cell.

Comment: Not really doable with formulas alone, as the formulas would have to evaluate each other which would give you circular references.

Comment: This gets at heart of problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716129/excel-formula-vba-to-keep-a-value-and-edit-cells-to-maintain-that-value/51717706#51717706

Answer (score 1):

You could add a helper column in which you keep track of the manually entered values. 
Let's say the Total value (12000) is in A1, months are in column A2:A13 and the helper column is column C.
Column B would then be;
=IF(C2<>"",C2,(A$1-SUM(C$2:C$13))/(12-COUNT(C$2:C$13)) for cell B2, simply extend to the other cells in column B

Comment: Thanks very much Chris I will try it.